# 315 MHz Receiver/Transmitter Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, transmitter, receiver, home-automation, automation

I bought a [receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T60QMIO) and transmitter (I can't find the link, but it says FS1000A and LR1 315.00 on it).

I also have a set of remote controlled wall outlets that operate on 315MHz according to the FCC website.

I plugged the receiver into a Raspberry Pi, and verified that the receiver was getting power with a multimeter, and sure enough it was getting 5V.

How do I read from the transmitter using the Pi? All of the software I found gives an error after a while, and I have no idea where to start with getting this.

Then, once I have the necessary code for the wall outlets, how do I transmit the code from Python/php?

Comment: Also I found [this](https://www.samkear.com/hardware/control-power-outlets-wirelessly-raspberry-pi) which is exactly what I want to do, but it uses software called '433Utils' - which didn't work with a 315Mhz receiver.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering SE. You might want to add infomation in the comments to the body of the question.

Comment: Why would the 433Utils not work with a 315MHz module ? My guess is that it **should** work because the software does not "know" if the RF signal is 315 or 433 MHz. The Transmit and receive modules must use the same RF frequency obviously but the software just switches the transmitter on and off. So I am quite sure something else is wrong instead of the 433utils not working because you're using 315 MHz instead of 433 Mhz.

Comment: I get an "uninterupted error" or something like that when I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that this question is getting a lot of views and I never answered it.

Yes, you can use 433Utils! The 315Mhz boards are identical to the 433Mhz boards except for the crystal.

Past that, something like homeassistant can be used to control your lights/whatever with a nice UI.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that your choice of receiver may be causing problems. The type of receiver you chose is the simplest type that can be ordered. Super-regenerative receivers work but are susceptible to noise and interference. Good quality receivers will have a specialized RF frontend that will convert to clean serial output.

From the product notes of another Super-regenerative receiver [similar product](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532):

> Note: These modules are indiscriminate and will receive a fair amount of noise. Both the transmitter and receiver work at common frequencies and don’t have IDs. Therefore, a method of filtering this noise and pairing transmitter and receiver will be necessary. The example code below shows such an example for basic operation. Please refer to the example code and links below for ways to accomplish a robust wireless data link.

With all that said, I briefly looked at the 433Utils mentioned in a few of the comments and it doesn't seem to have any specialized filtering on the input. This could lead to lots of unexpected behavior (especially if there are other devices on the same frequency).

First if you have access to an oscilloscope, I'd inspect the output of the receiver and make sure you have clean transitions between logic high and logic low. If you don't you might need to get a different receiver or get one with an appropriate demodulator (I can try and explain if this becomes an issue).

If not, I'd try and follow the [instructions](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/) for the same type of receiver and see if you can get it to work at least receiving serial data.

In terms of eventually transmitting to the outlets, once you have your transmitter/receiver working, it will as easy as following the [guide](https://www.samkear.com/hardware/control-power-outlets-wirelessly-raspberry-pi) mentioned in the comments.